# how shall I update a webpart on page using SharePoint web services

Tags: 2007, web-part, web-services

Which method I can use to hide a webpart on a page using SharePoint web services for sharepoint 2007.

Thanks
Sophia London

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `SaveWebPart()` built-in web services to update webpart on a page,

```
[SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://microsoft.com/sharepoint/webpartpages/SaveWebPart", RequestNamespace="http://microsoft.com/sharepoint/webpartpages", ResponseNamespace="http://microsoft.com/sharepoint/webpartpages", Use=SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)] 
public void SaveWebPart (
    string pageUrl,
    Guid storageKey,
    string webPartXml,
    Storage storage
)
```

[WebPartPagesWebService.SaveWebPart Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774839%28v=office.12%29.aspx)